# Different standard views in subsites

Tags: web-part, document-library, list-view, view, library

i am trying to achieve the following. 
I have created a site with shared documents (let's call it control)
Then i created 3 sub sites under "control" (alpha, beta and gamma?)
I create a web part from the shared documents in "Control", and i import it in Alpha, Beta and Gamma.

What i need now is for the three different sub sites, to have 3 different standard views on the web part (viewalpha, viewbeta and viewgamma)

The reason for this is because i want to have 3 columns in the shared documents control group that can be switched on or off, depending if the documents are applicable for Alpha, Beta or Gamma.

This way, only the documents that are applicable for those groups will show up in the sub sites.

At this moment however, if i put a standard view on one (let's say i choose viewalpha), all three sub sites are switched to the same standard view.

Could anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a list or library to a page, you can choose default view for that list or library on that page. Go to "Edit Web Part" section on the page you add the library.